# which statistical test should i use for my project?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, spss

i have conducted an experiment with two conditions (happy and sad) i wanted to see the effects of these conditions on words chosen from three different categories (positive, negative and neutral words)

-in both conditions i have data on the three different word categories

its a between subjects design - their were different paricipants in each condition
the IV is the mood condition either happy or sad

the DV is realtive frequency of words in pos, neg and neutral categories

i want to find a statistical test which will show me if there is a difference between the realtive frequencies in each word category in the two different conditions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a table with rows Happy/Sad and
columns Pos/Neg/Neut. Find word counts for
each of the $2\times 3 = 6$ cells.

Then do a chi-squared test to see if Pos/Neg/Neut
choices are homogeneously distributed for Happy and
Sad populations.

To illustrate how `chisq.test` works in R, consider
the following table with fictitious counts:

```
TBL = rbind(c(21,34, 53), c(65, 27, 10))
TBL
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   21   34   53
[2,]   65   27   10

chisq.test(TBL)

       Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 52.536, df = 2, p-value = 3.909e-12
```

For these data the null hypothesis of homogeneity is strongly
rejected with a P-value near $0.$ So it seems Happy and Sad
people are picking different kinds of words.

There are lots of examples of chi-squared tests of homogeneity
on this site and on various online help pages. [For possibilities on this site you might start with the
"Related" links in the margin of this page.]

- If you get an
  error message for your real data complaining about inability
  to get a reliable P-value on account of low counts in some cells,
  you might be able to use the argument `sim=T` in `chisq.test` to
  get a useful P-value.
- If you wonder whether additional tests might be useful to
  try to track down what specific differences in word  type there
  are between Happy and Sad people, you may get some ideas from
  similar sources. Maybe use `$` notation `chisq.test(TBL)$resi` for clues from 'Pearson residuals'.

Whatever happens: If you get stuck analyzing your real data, then please post the table of real counts
and explain your quandary. Then one of us might be able to help.